# Using the weight output of factor.scores function in R to index latent variable

Tags: categorical-data, factor-analysis

I have a questionnaire with 8 correlated items, containing negative and positive items. I want to know the weight of each question or item on latent variable or  factor. 
I ran factor analysis and after that the factor.scores function in R. the output gives me some weights like below:

```
> factor.scores(Factor.data, solution, method = c("Thurstone"))

$weights
           PA1
t1 -0.09892204
t2 -0.03569024
t3 -0.09805321
t4  0.15305617
t5  0.06727965
t7  0.20378106
t8  0.36781613
t9  0.14807168
```

I want to know what exactly these weights are? Can I use them as questions weights to give an index to latent variable?

Comment: Can you provide the code / function calls you used to get this output? What language is this, R?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, yes this is in R with factor.scores function.